# Custom Validation attribute not working on client side

Tags: c#, .net, validation, asp.net-core-2.0, customvalidator

I have create following custom requiredif attribute and added client side script also validation is working on server side. tag is updated with data-val attributes but client side validation is not triggering. Couldn't figure aout what's I am missing here

```
public class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator//ValidationAttribute
    {
        private string dependentProperty;
        private object targetValue;
        public RequiredIfAttribute(string _DependentProperty, object _TargetValue) 
        {
            this.dependentProperty=_DependentProperty  ;
            this.targetValue=_TargetValue  ;
        }

        public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-requiredif-dependentproperty", dependentProperty);
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-requiredif-targetvalue","true");
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-requiredif",GetErrorMessage(context));
    }
        bool MergeAttribute(IDictionary<string, string> attributes, string key, string value)
        {
            if (attributes.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                return false;
            }
            attributes.Add(key, value);
            return true;
        }

        private string GetErrorMessage(ClientModelValidationContext context)
        {
            return string.Format("{0} is not a valid",
                context.ModelMetadata.GetDisplayName());
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var propertyTestedInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(this.dependentProperty);

            if (propertyTestedInfo == null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(string.Format("{0} needs to be exist in this object.", this.dependentProperty));
            }

            var dependendValue = propertyTestedInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            if (dependendValue == null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(string.Format("{0} needs to be populated.", this.dependentProperty));
            }

            if (!dependendValue.Equals(this.targetValue))
            {
                var fieldValue = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(validationContext.MemberName).GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);


                if (fieldValue != null)
                {
                    return ValidationResult.Success;
                }
                else
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(string.Format("{0} cannot be null", validationContext.MemberName));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Must be ignored
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
        }

    }
```

Javascript Code

```
<script>

    $.validator.addMethod('requiredif',
        function (value, element, parameters) {
            var id = '#' + parameters['dependentproperty'];
            // get the target value (as a string,
            // as that's what actual value will be)
            var targetvalue = parameters['targetvalue'];
            targetvalue =
                (targetvalue == null ? '' : targetvalue).toString();

            // get the actual value of the target control
            // note - this probably needs to cater for more
            // control types, e.g. radios
            var control = $(id);

            var controltype = control.attr('type');
            var actualvalue =
                controltype === 'checkbox' ?
                    control.attr('checked').toString() :
                    control.val();

            // if the condition is true, reuse the existing
            // required field validator functionality
            if (targetvalue === actualvalue)

            return $.validator.methods.required.call(
                this, value, element, parameters);

            return true;
        }
    );

    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
        'requiredif',
        ['dependentproperty', 'targetvalue'],
        function (options) {

            options.rules['requiredif'] = {
                dependentproperty: options.params['dependentproperty'],
                targetvalue: options.params['targetvalue']
            };
            options.messages['requiredif'] = options.message;
        });
</script>
```

Generated Tag and class property are as follows

```
<select data-val-requiredif="ToPositionID is not a valid" data-val-requiredif-dependentproperty="chkToPosReq"         data-val-requiredif-targetvalue="true" id="ToPositionID" name="ToPositionID">
```

**Class**

```
public class VMWorkflow
    {
        [RequiredIf("chkToPosReq", "1")]
        public int? ToPositionID { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: On client side is select has attribute for dependent property and it’s target value?

Comment: I have added attribute but still no success